# Remove and Override WooCommerce Process Registration action

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a plugin to customise the woocommerce registration and trying to avoid direct editing of the core files.

I need to override or replace `process_registration` action in woocommerces `includes/class-wc-form-handler.php` file through my plugin.

```
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'process_registration' ) );
```

I tried following links, but they didn't work. Also, the files mentioned on those pages doesn't exist on woocommerce current version. I also checked woocommerce documentation, but it seems they don't have a hook for that.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/overriding-woocommerce_process_registration-in-child-theme-functionsphp

Woocommerce Hooks:
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/

I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: The solution in the first url should help you. Did you try that?

Comment: Hi Rahil, Yes, I tried that, but didn't work. Also, woocommerce-functions.php and woocommerce-hooks.php files not included in the current version of the woocommerce.

Comment: It should be somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Two options for that and considering that WC method starts like:

```
class WC_Form_Handler
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'process_registration' ) );
    }
    public function process_registration() {
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['register'] ) ) {
            wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['register'], 'woocommerce-register' );
            # etc
        }
    }
}
new WC_Form_Handler();
```

1. Add an `init` hook with top priority and duplicate then `unset($_POST['register'])`.  WC doesn't specify a priority, so it's running on 10, which is default.

   ```
   add_action( 'init', function() { /* dup, unset, do your thing */ }, 1 ); // priority 1
   ```
2. Track down that [evil anonymous object](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57079/12615) where Woo is hidding its hook, so that you can:

   ```
   // pseudo code, go to WPSE for the real thing
   remove_hook( 'init', 'woo_process_registration' );
   ```